# React App breaks after changing data directly in mysql database

Tags: reactjs, api, axios, use-effect, use-state

I am new to React, and I'm currently learning about `useState` and `useEffect`. I have successfully fetched data from my local api using `axios`. For development purposes, I'm intentionally changing the data directly from my database, to see if data changes would reflect in my React app. But, whenever I do so, my app breaks. I have included a screenshot of the error.

Here is my code:

```
function App() {
  const[applicant, setApplicant] = useState("");
 
  useEffect(() => {
     axios.get("http://localhost:5000/application/1")
     .then((res) => {
        setApplicant(res.data);
        console.log(res.data.personalInfo.firstName);
     })
     .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  }, []);

  return (
    <div><h1>Welcome {applicant.personalInfo.firstName}</h1></div>
  );
}
```

So here's the weird part (at least for me). On first load, everything works perfectly fine. But when I change `first_name` field directly in my database, my app breaks. Here's the screenshot:

[image]

Obervation 1: if I change the array dependency of my `useEffect` to always look at changes in `applicant` state, the error will not occur. But as you might have already guessed, it causes an infinite loop request.

Observation 2: after my app breaks due to changes in database, if I temporarily remove that part in my JSX where I rendered the fetched data in my component: `<h1>Welcome {applicant.personalInfo.firstName}</h1>`, refresh the page, then paste it back again, and refresh again, the error disappears, and the newly updated `first_name` renders successfully.

Can someone tell me what's going on here, and mybe a better way of implementing this? Thanks a lot!

Edit: This is a screenshot of my json data:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the problem. Basically, the type of my state is string, but in my `setApplicant()`, I'm setting its value to the returned json object. So I just changed the default state type to be an empty object, like so:

`const[applicant, setApplicant] = useState({});`

Then, in my `useEffect` hook:

`setApplicant(res.data.personalInfo); //setting it to personalInfo object`

Then, to access its attributes:

`<h1>Welcome {applicant.firstName}</h1>`